# Почему программа на Xlib вызывает сбой ОС

Tags: c, xlib

Написал простейшую программу на Xlib для Debian 9:

```
#include <X11/Xlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main ()
{
    Display* disp = XOpenDisplay (":0:);
    if (disp == NULL)
    {
        printf ("Cannot open display");
        exit (1);
    }

    char c = 0;
    while (1)
    {
        scanf ("%c", &c);
        if (c == 'с') break;
    }

    XCloseDisplay (disp)
    exit (0);
}
```

После этого я запускаю дисплейный сервер командой `sudo Xorg` и запускаю программу. Если нормально завершить программу, набрав в консоли `c`, а затем переключиться на X сервер, то операционная система намертво зависнет, до аварийной перезагрузки. Что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 0):

Думаю, у вас проблема не в программе, а в видеодрайвере.

Соответственно, рекомендации: иксы запускайте раз навсегда через xdm (gdm, lightdm) и не переключайтесь в консоль, а запускайте свою программу из открытого в иксах терминала.

Comment: Дело в том, что демонстрационые приложения (Xlogo, Xeyes и т.д.) запускаются нормально.